# Access the default created Viewcontroller object

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In my iOS newsstand app i need to access the default created viewContoller object in my appDelegate to start the background download when a notification arrives.

The problem is the viewController i want to access is not the root viewcontroller, if  thats the case i can access it as follows,

```
MyViewController* mainController = (MyViewController*)  self.window.rootViewController;
```

It would be great if anyone could guide me on this.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried as following methods,

In your `AppDelegate.h`.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) HAViewController * haViewController;
```

In your `AppDelegate.m`

```
@synthesize haViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.haViewController = [[HAViewController alloc] init];

    return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [self.haViewController startupdate];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yp thought of it,but in my case im using the storyboard and im using a Master viewcontroller using SASlideMenu. So cant do like that. Thanks . any suggestion.